H-NMR of methyl salicylate
I am analysing the H-NMR spectrum of methyl salicylate (see image below). There are several signals in the aromatic region.
Because of the electron-withdrawing ester moiety, protons 3 and 5 appear more downfield (higher ppm). The signal of proton 3 at 7.67 ppm is split into a doublet of doublets.
I have difficulty interpreting the other signals in the aromatic region.
The signal at 7.29 ppm appears to me as a triplet of doublets. This is to be expected for proton 5. However, in the middle, a triplet is clearly visible? Is this the solvent peak (CDCl3) or is there another reason?
The signal at 6.75 ppm appears to be comprised of a triplet, doublet, triplet, doublet. Proton 6 is expected to give a doublet of doublets, while proton 4 is expected to give a triplet of doublets. Why does the spectrum then show a triplet, doublet, triplet, doublet? Is this because the signals of proton 4 and 6 overlap?
Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you in advance!


There is a helpful post on the NMR spectrum of Aspirin, but strangely the spectrum looks quite different (even the chemical shifts).

The The signals at far right are belong to protons 4 and 6. Proton 4 resonates at around $\pu{6.7 ppm}$ as a triplet (forget long range coupling) while  proton 6 resonates at around $\pu{6.85 ppm}$ as a doublet. Note that these two signals are partially overlapped.

Thank you for your help! Why are then four peaks observed at the far right, if proton 4 resonates as a triplet and proton 6 as a doublet?

As I said one proton doublet (proton 6) and one proton triplet (proton 4) are overlapped, thus they look like four peaks instead of five.

Thank you for your help!
